# Elementary program fails to load (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I am trying to load the following program

```
gcd a b = if b == 0
         then a
      else gcd b (rem a b)
```

But I get the error

```
Prelude> :l euclidean.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( euclidean.hs, interpreted )

euclidean.hs:3:8:
    Ambiguous occurrence `gcd'
    It could refer to either `Main.gcd', defined at euclidean.hs:1:0
                          or `Prelude.gcd', imported from Prelude
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I changed the function name from `gcd` to `main` and I get

```
Couldn't match expected type `IO t'
           against inferred type `a -> a -> a'
    In the expression: main
    When checking the type of the function `main'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I dont understand this. I am using the [workshop](http://bos.github.com/strange-loop-2011/slides/slides.html#%2829%29) step here.

Comment: Don't use tabs as indentation.

Comment: @MatveyB.Aksenov Is there any specific reason why?

Comment: Tabs in Haskell are defined to be 8 spaces. This may not be the way your (or your collaborators) editor displays them which would lead to confusing errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269888/invisible-identation-error-in-haskell-caused-load-fail-in-ghci or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694097/haskell-compiler-error-not-in-scope or dozens similar posts here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first error should be self-evident--a function called `gcd` already exists.

The second one is also simple. In Haskell, `main` is the entry point of the program. Since the program needs some way to do IO, `main` has to have a type in the form `IO a`, usually `IO ()`. What this means is you should call your `gcd` function something else. (The `main` function in Haskell is akin to the `main` method in Java.)

The usual practice is to call it `gcd'`, which is pronounced "gcd prime". In this case, naming your function `gcd'` signifies that it is just a different implementation of `gcd`.